# Do we have to use useCallback hook with React.memo to optimized the rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-usecallback

I was checking how useCallback and useMemo work and how this helps to optimized the performance of the app.

I have created a simple app to understand. What I found is that the callback (OnBlurHandler) which I am passing to my child component is causing the rendering of the component every time the parent component is rendering. So to optimized it I wrapped that callback in useCallback to avoid the re-rendering.

But to my surprise the component still renders even after the using the useCallback. So, I wrap the child component in React.memo and I am able to achieve what I want.

But I am not able to understand why the child component is rendering just using the useCallback. Why do we need to wrap the child component into react.memo.

```
// Parent Component
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo, useCallback } from "react";
import Input from "./Input";

const UnderStadingHooks = () => {
  console.log("Component Start");     
  const [a, setA] = useState(0);
  const [b, setB] = useState(0);
  const [rdm, setRdm] = useState(0);
  let c;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("UseEffect Start");
    c = a + b;
    console.log(a, b, c, d);
  }, [a, b]);

  const d = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("UseMemo Called");
    return a + b;
  }, [a, b]);

  const OnBlurHandler = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      console.log("OnBLur Hablder called");
      if (e.target.name === "a") {
        setA(parseInt(e.target.value));
      } else {
        setB(parseInt(e.target.value));
      }
    },
    [a, b]
  );

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    const ran = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
    setRdm(ran);
  };
  console.log("Component END");
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Understanding Hooks In Depth</h1>
      <Input
        name="a"
        placeholder="Enter a Value of A"
        OnBlurHandler={OnBlurHandler}
      />
      <Input
        name="b"
        placeholder="Enter a value of B"
        OnBlurHandler={OnBlurHandler}
      />
      <p>
        Values are :{a},{b}
      </p>
      <p>SumEffect:{c}</p>
      <p>SumMemo:{d}</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleOnClick}>
        Display Some Random Number
      </button>
      <p>{rdm}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export { UnderStadingHooks };
```

```
// Child Component
import React, { memo } from "react";

const Input = ({ name, placeholder, id, OnBlurHandler }) => {
  console.log("Input Component Rendered");
  return (
    <input
      id={id}
      name={name}
      placeholder={placeholder}   
      onBlur={OnBlurHandler} 
    />
  );
};

export default memo(Input);
```

Comment: A bit of advice if your new to React, once you understand how `React.memo`, `useCallback` work,  forget they exist and use a global state manager, eg. something like https://jotai.org/ is a really nice and simple one.  By doing this you get granular updates, pretty much to the same level as SolidJS, and things like `React.memo` are rarely ever needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a very common misunderstanding actually. The thing is when a parent component re-renders, it triggers the re-rending of its children (cascading to all its descendants). That happens no matter what props actually changed.

So if you want to avoid the re-rendering of a child component, you need to do both the things you did:

1. use `memo` on your component in order to check if any prop changed using shallow equality (===).
2. make sure no prop changes everytime (if not necessary) and that's where `useCallback`, `useMemo` hooks come into play.

###### Further reading/digging

I wasn't able to find official docs where this behaviour is well presented, however you can see more on this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/wdv4p9/does_a_component_rerender_only_when_its_props/), which contains useful links if you want to dig into the react rendering process.

A very interesting note is that this behavior is usually misunderstood by a lot of people coming from the redux world, because [redux connect applies the memo mechanism](https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data#how-does-react-redux-use-shallow-equality-checking-to-determine-whether-a-component-needs-re-rendering) (shallow prop comparison) on components by default.

Comment: Thank you for the insights. It clears a lot of confusion and misunderstanding. Just one more clarification I need on the point that when we talk about useCallback & useMemo hook to optimized the performance of the app, we say that these hooks returns a memorized function & value respectively. What exactly it means & how does the memorization works.

Comment: When using these hooks, you inform react that it does not need to re-calculate the value or the function on the right side of the assignment, until anything from the dependencies array changes.
In your example, `OnBlurHandler` will be re-calculated and re-assigned on every component update. After useCallback it will be recalculated only when `a` or `b` changes (which does not make sense, since it does not actually depends on these values - you could totally omit them)

Comment: Just remember that memorization comes with its own cost, so you don't have to memorize everything just to avoid some re-renderings.
Use memorization hooks when you need to avoid some heavy calculations or the rendering of a heavy component.